# How does GLIBC decide segment for malloc

Tags: gdb, malloc, heap-memory, glibc, mmap

I look at some Linux Glibc(2.25) system and see that when the code use `malloc`  .

sometimes the buffer has been allocated at heap segment and sometimes in anonymous segment, It's not relate for size, I can see all the segments in `/proc/PID/maps`

I thought that the heap segment relate for `malloc` And anonymous segment relate for `mmap`. But why GLIBC decide for the same size to use `malloc` and sometimes use `mmap`

I saw that sometimes when I use `malloc` in some thread the memory has been allocated at heap segment but when I switch for another thread(using GDB) the memory has been allocated to anonymous segment

Answer (score 0):

glibc's `malloc` implementation will sometimes use `brk` or `sbrk` (what you're calling the heap -- it shows up as 'heap' in /proc/PID/maps) and sometimes use `mmap`.  Which depends on some tradeoffs, but generally

- if a process only needs a small amount of heap space, brk/sbrk is better
- if a process needs a lot of heap space and/or very large blocks, mmap is better.

So GLIBC's malloc implementation has a bunch of heuristics to decide what is 'small' and what is 'large' and looks at what calls have been made so far to malloc/free in order decide on which method to use to get more memory from the system when it needs it.

There's a function `mallopt` you can call that affects this tuning -- there's a bunch of info on the man page about it.

Comment: But I use `malloc` through GDB and in some thread the buffer has been allocated in heap segment and in a other thread (same process) the buffer has been allocated in anonymous segment. I'm both way I allocates the same size!